# presupposition and trigger in emphatic sentences

Tags: grammar, pragmatics, presupposition

It was Jenny who stole the cake from the bakery.

I'm learning presuppositions & trigger words in my linguistics class. In an emphatic sentence like above am I correct in my understanding that...

the presupposition is "Someone stole the cake from the bakery"
trigger is: "It was Jenny"

Thank you!

Comment: You might say that "who" presupposes a referent, and that's the trigger. ("It" and "Jenny" both indicate the same entity as "who".)

Comment: This is an _it_-cleft (from _Jenny stole the cake from the bakery_), and the presupposition comes from the construction. The second part of the cleft, after _Jenny_, is a restrictive relative clause, and [that is the trigger for the presupposition](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf), since material in relatives is presupposed.